# Remote Server doesn't response to client request - using Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I'm learning Java RMI so that i'm writing and testing this code, the problem here is that the client (notificationSink class) send a message and register itself with the server but the server (notificationSource class) doesn't do anything.

This is `RemoteThingInterface` that extends `Remote` class:

```
public interface RemoteThingInterface extends Remote{
    public void register(NotificationSink sink) throws RemoteException;
    public void notifySink(String text) throws RemoteException;    
}
```

This is NotificationSink class:

```
public class NotificationSink{
    private String name;
    private static String hostName = "Shine";
    private static int serverPort = 2712;
    private static String text = (new Date()).toString();

    public NotificationSink(String name){
        name = this.name;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        RemoteThingInterface rmiserver;
        Registry reg;
        System.out.println("Sending "+text+" to "+hostName+" through port "+serverPort);

        try{
            reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(hostName, serverPort); 

            rmiserver = (RemoteThingInterface) reg.lookup("server");

            NotificationSink s = new NotificationSink("Eagle 1");

            rmiserver.register(s);

            rmiserver.notifySink(text);
        }catch(RemoteException ex){} catch (NotBoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

This is `NotificationSource` class:

```
public class NotificationSource extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteThingInterface{
    private ArrayList sinks = new ArrayList<>();
    int port;
    Registry registry;

    public NotificationSource() throws RemoteException{
        try{
            port = 2712;
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            registry.rebind("server", this);
        }catch(RemoteException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void register(NotificationSink sink) {
        sinks.add(sink);
    }

    public ArrayList getSinks(){
        return sinks;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifySink(String text){        
        System.out.println("new sink registered, he is "+getSinks().get(0));
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            NotificationSource s = new NotificationSource();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help to explain where i'm wrong and how to fix this. I tried to add some code to find the size of arraylist in server, it find out successfully, but other methods don't work .... codes are below:

adding this line to remotethinginterface: `ArrayList getArray() throws RemoteException;`

adding this line to notiSource:

```
@Override
    public ArrayList getArray() throws RemoteException {
        return sinks;
    }
```

adding this line to notiSink: `System.out.println(rmiserver.getArray().size());` (before `rmiserver.register()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the client (notificationSink class) send a message

No it doesn't.

> and register itself with the server

No it doesn't.

> but the server (notificationSource class) doesn't do anything.

Why should it? There is no client request to do anything with. There can't be. It's impossible.

```
catch(RemoteException ex){}
```

The first major problem is here. You are ignoring `RemoteException`. Don't do that. Log it, print it, never ignore an exception unless you *really* know what you're doing. In this case you will therefore have ignored the nested `NotSerializableException` that was thrown when you called `register().`

The second major problem is that `NotificationSink` needs to either:

1. Implement `Serializable`, if you want it to execute at the server, or
2. Implement a remote interface and extend `UnicastRemoteObject,` if you want it to execute at the client.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! You've just reminded me an important thing is serializable object to be passed as parameters of remote method. Thank you!!!

Comment: I think you'll find you really want #2 here, but we'll see.

Comment: I will try both option to see what is happening with the output :) Btw, can you please explain why if i change `registry` to `Naming` it doesn't work ?? i compare but they are not different at all. But when i replace registry with Naming, i have an error: `Connection refused`

Comment: Error at the line `source = (SourceInterface) Naming.lookup("server"); `

Comment: I found that, if i add the port number to rebind in source and loopup in sink. It works! But why i see there are many example that doesn't have the port number there, it still work. i know that if we not specify a port number, the default port would be 1099 right??? then why it doesn't work .... ??

Comment: Your lookup string is ambiguous. It looks like a hostname without the port. When you specify the port you must also provide the missing / which disambiguates it. You should use "//localhost/server".